# Python function returning different values depending on prior inputs

Tags: python, function

Learning python on Codeacademy.
This is a simple program for Pig Latin Translator.
As the title says, depending on prior inputs(which are intentionally entered incorrect), the function is returning different(first) value instead of latest value as cleared by if else. I tried to put return inside else but as seen in #Reference the local variable isn't returned. Please help.

```
def string_check():
    name = raw_input("Enter a word")
    if len(name) == 0 or name.isalpha() == False:
        print "Enter a valid word"
        string_check()
    else:
        print name
    return name

print 'Welcome to the Pig Latin Translator!'

# Start coding here!
original = string_check()
print ("Original variable is " +original)
ans = original[1:len(original)] + original[0] + "ay"
print ("Pig Latin word is %s"% (ans))

# Reference
omega = 3
if omega == 3:
    print "Obvious"
    beta = 5
    print beta
print beta
```

## OUTPUT

1: When I entered a blank as first input

```
Welcome to the Pig Latin Translator!
Enter a word 
Enter a valid word
Enter a word 123
Enter a valid word
Enter a word 123gas
Enter a valid word
Enter a word gas
gas
Original variable is 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python", line 15, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
```

2: When I entered first input as 123

```
Welcome to the Pig Latin Translator!
Enter a word 123
Enter a valid word
Enter a word 
Enter a valid word
Enter a word 123gas
Enter a valid word
Enter a word 
Enter a valid word
Enter a word gas
gas
Original variable is 123
Pig Latin word is 231ay
Obvious
5 
5
None
```

3. When I enter correct input directly

```
Welcome to the Pig Latin Translator!
Enter a word gas
gas
Original variable has gas
Pig Latin word is asgay
Obvious
5
5
None
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `string_check` function you call itself on line 4. The returned result (`name`) is not captured however. One solution is to replace `string_check()` on line 4 with `name = string_check()`.